# why GetComponent returns null reference for imageEffect?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

this problem is unsolvable or what?i don't need to provide any code example it just doesn't work to anyone!and i don't know how its possible,you just have to try this :  `GetComponent<DepthOfField>().enabled = false;`

assume that we have a `MainCamera` object and we attach it a `DepthOfField` image effect Script.and we create another script named `whatever` and attach it to the `MainCamera` and in the `whatever` script we just call this:

```
void Start() {
  GetComponent<DepthOfField>().enabled = false;
}
```

shouldn't it work?well it doesn't, it returns null reference exception even if the script is attached to the main camera.is it fixable? and if yes i need it !

Comment: The problem could be that DepthOfField is a class from javascript / unityscript and you're trying to access it from C#. There was some dependency issue if I recall correctly, which either allowed you to access C# classes from JS, or the other way round, but not both. In the newer unity versions, all the post effects have been rewritten as C# classes. So, rewriting your custom component `whatever` as a Javascript/Unityscript component could fix your issue.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to google before posting, similar question here http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/707774/cant-access-depth-of-field.html, one of the answers redirect you to a proper solution for your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work because they are both attached to the same GameObject. Although, there are many other ways you can try to fix this.

You can just do

```
 DepthOfField myDept;

void Start() {
myDept = GameObject.Find("MainCamera").GetComponent<DepthOfField>();
myDept.enabled = false;
}
```

Or You could make DepthOfField **public** then assign the DepthOfField from the Editor. For example,

```
public DepthOfField myDept;
```

//Drag and Drop the MainCamera GameObject from the scene to this and it will automatically assign the DepthOfField script to the myDept.

Then you can do

```
myDept.enabled = false;
```

For this to work, DepthOfField  must be attached to the MainCamera GameObject.

Comment: the problem was that i had 2 DepthOfField scripts in my project and it was getting dizzy